# @font-face suddenly won't work

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

This worked perfectly:

```
@font-face
{
    FONT-FAMILY: "Delia Regular";
    SRC: url("/Fonts/Delia Regular.ttf");
}
```

Then I changed it to:

```
@font-face
{
    FONT-FAMILY: "Delia Regular";
    SRC: url("/Fonts/Delia Regular.ttf?#IE") format("truetype");
}
```

and it didn't work.

I changed it back to the first example, and it still doesn't work. I am using latest version of Firefox on Windows 10 x64. I cleared cache and flushed DNS, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion on how should I make it work again? I also tried adding #iefix instead of #IE - nothing changed. The problem is the same with the latest Chrome. Other fonts still work normally with both examples, I am having problem just with this one.

Comment: When you say you changed it back, did you go back to the code exactly as it was (e.g. by undoing or using source control), or did you type it back in? I'm suspecting a typo when reentering the code.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Yes, exactly as it was, but nothing changed although it worked normally before I changed it.

Comment: You need to add the font families properly, with all compatibility possible. You need a TTF, a WOFF and a OTF file, and then add them with the propper code. You can use https://onlinefontconverter.com/ to convert your files and it gives you the final code to include in your site. By this mode all works fine. DNS flushing is not neccesary for this purposes.

Comment: @Aroniaina Also excluded, because I used the correct path of the other fonts included in the CSS file. I just changed the font name.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes Marcos, I tried format("ttf") and format("truetype"). No change. I prefer using .ttf, I did not expect this especially because it worked normally before the switch.

Comment: I talk to you about most possible compatibility. TTF is not full compatible, see the table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf . Use more than TTF files as I suggest you and you solve all the problems instantly. And this task is a 5 minutes work copy&paste. Don't be lazy ;)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Ah okay. I will try. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Failed to convert the font.

Comment: Sorry, this web is better. http://www.font2web.com/ And maybe, your font files are corrupted or are not original, so you can't use them safely. If it is happen, download the font by the oficial sources.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude This one managed to convert the font to multiple formats, but the problem persists. If it is corrupted, would it work at all? The problem occured an hour ago, and it worked normally ever since I first used it 6 months ago until an hour ago.

Comment: Are you using a control version system? Like GIT, SVN, Mercurial... ? Go back in time and recover your lost code. However, the code that you post in the question is not safely to work. I don't write that code never in my webpages. So I suggest to you that you must to change all your code and the font files

Comment: If you're absolutely certain that this CSS is now the same as it was before and it doesn't work the way it did, the question becomes: what _else_ did you change? Did the markup change so that it no longer tries to apply this font, did you update a browser to a version that no longer supports TTF, etc.